# Is Javascript synchronous when manipulating the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, synchronous

I have a form with an input of type field. I have several radiobuttons, and depending on which of them I click, the value in the input type field will be updated. After that, I will call a Javascript function to perform certain action, and the function will use the updated quantity (text) in the input field.

Of course, it is more secure to pass that quantity to the function itself, but could I rely on Javascript first updating the DOM, displaying the update input field value, and with that, retrieving it via`document.getElementById("input-quantity").value` and using this in the function? Or could the function get the "old" value if the refresh of the DOM takes its time?

Comment: to get your value updated fields you have to include script inside DOMContentLoaded listener event.. better keep your values in session attributes..

Comment: Better not to first put the value in the DOM via JS and then read the value back from the DOM. just use it, pass it around or store it somewhere.

Comment: @ABUdhay - No you don't.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you said, just passing the value to the function would be preferred.

But yes, setting the value of an input is synchronous; in what you describe, you will reliably get the updated value, cross-browser. Other DOM manipulations (inserting elements, removing them, moving them) are also synchronous, although the user may not see the result until your JavaScript code completes, letting the browser use the thread to repaint the display. (Although JavaScript is not inherently single-threaded, browsers use a single main UI thread to run your JavaScript code, and typically also use that thread to update the display.)

Comment: Could you give any reference of your conclusion? And how to explain long running javascript code block UI updates?

Comment: @Charvis: See [the Jobs and Job Queues section of the ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) and various parts of the HTML specification, particularly [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.html#serializability-of-script-execution) and [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.html#common-pitfalls-to-avoid-when-using-the-scripting-apis). If you have a specific question about long-running scripts, post a question! :-) (You'll have to define what you mean by "long-running scripts" in the question.)

Comment: Do you happen to know if setting `element.style.display` in particular is guaranteed to be synchronous? It seems to be synchronous from my testing, but I don't know if that will be the case in every browser/machine/circumstance.

Comment: @V.Rubinetti - Yes, it is. But rendering the change won't happen until the browser next has the opportunity to render, which is usually only between tasks (on most browsers).